# Webpack Hot Reload very slow

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

I'm quite new to Webpack and when I initially set it up with my project it was working great but it seems to have got much slower as my project has progressed (maybe because more and more packages get included?). It's now taking over 1 second according to the console output:

[image]

This does not seem accurate though because in reality it's taking between 5 and 10 seconds and usually I just get bored of waiting and hit F5 to reload the page because it'll just be quicker. I'd like to get back to letting HMR do it's thing but I need to figure out why it's so slow and fix before I can do that.

Here is my **webpack.config.js**:

```
/// <binding />
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

const dirName = 'wwwroot/dist';
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
console.log('path:' + path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/images'));

module.exports =  {
    mode: devMode ? 'development' : 'production',
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
        app: './wwwroot/js/app.ts',
        addadv: './wwwroot/js/pages/adventures/addadventure.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, dirName),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'initial'
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: require.resolve('jquery'),
                loader: 'expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery'
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node-modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[c|a]ss$/,
                use: [
                    'css-hot-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            config: {
                                ctx: {
                                    env: devMode ? 'development' : 'production'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'resolve-url-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'fonts/'
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/images')
                ],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'images',
                            publicPath: 'images'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(dirName, {}),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "bundle.css",
            chunkFilename: "bundle.css"
        }),
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: 'disabled',
            generateStatsFile: true,
            statsOptions: { source: false }
        })
    ]
};
```

and my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tap.extranet",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch-dev": "webpack --watch",
    "build-dev": "webpack",
    "build-prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "analyse-bundles": "webpack-bundle-analyzer --port 4200 wwwroot/dist/stats.json"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.7.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "@types/jqueryui": "1.12.7",
    "@types/jquery.validation": "1.16.6",
    "@types/jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.32",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.7",
    "@types/knockout": "^3.4.64",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.4.7",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-hot-loader": "^1.4.3",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.8",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "font-awesome-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "precss": "^4.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.5.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.3",
    "knockout": "3.5.0",
    "knockout-sortable": "1.1.0",
    "jquery-ui": "1.12.1"
  },
  "-vs-binding": {
    "BeforeBuild": [
      "build-dev"
    ],
    "ProjectOpened": [
      "watch-dev"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
  }
}
```

and finally, here is a screenshot of my bundles:

[image]

I've tried adding `cache: true` to the webpack config but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: This is because of `generateStatsFile: true`. We need to set this to false for dev environment